# How to enable event bubbling on return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi following is my html.

```
// consider all are of same size
<div id="grand-parent">
   <div id="parent">
      <div id = "child">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript.

```
$("#grand-parent").click(function(){
    alert("grand-parent");
});

$("#parent").click(function(){
    alert("grand-parent");
});

 // consider this as child event but actual child event comes from third party.
$("#parent").click(function(){
   return false;
});
```

The events are bind in the order of child, parent, grand-parent.
Now when i click on div child element event will trigger first return false. This will stop event bubbling. But I want the grand-parent div click event also  needs to be triggered.

Blockers: Child click event will always bind first and it is third party api so we cant touch.

Any Help can be appreciated.

Comment: If your `parent` click does nothing, than unbind this event.

Comment: try with `mousedown()` instead of `click()` it will before trigger of click

Comment: @Justinas The child event is happens in third party js. I cant edit. Is there any way to enable the click event on grand-parent.

Comment: @prasad click event will trigger for both click and touch. I am not aware that mousedown will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code, if you click on child then first grand parent will trigger, then child and then parent. If you click on parent, grand parent event will trigger, then parent and if you click on grand parent, it will trigger grand parent only. 
In this code i am applying event capturing concept, so grand parent will call first then, control goes to child then parent.

JS fiddle link -

https://jsfiddle.net/oe1qxsub/

**HTML -**

```
<div id="grand-parent">
<div id="parent">
  <div id = "child">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS -**

```
$("#grand-parent").get(0).addEventListener("click", function(){
 alert("grand-parent");
}, true);



$("#parent").click(function(){
 alert("parent");
});


$("#child").click(function(){
 alert('child');
});
```

**CSS -**

```
#grand-parent{
 background:blue;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
}
#parent{
 background:red;
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
}
#child{
 background:yellow;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the `useCapture` parameter of `addEventListener` when registering on the grand-parent.

This will call the grand-parent event before calling the child's event.

See [the doc for addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).